# Will "The Modern Literal Translation of the Bible" HELP STOP the growth of NEW Christian Sects?

Tags: translation-philosophy

**[Please go to this link to download a free copy of the "Modern Literal Translation" of the bible into e-Sword, MyBible, MySword and soon MLV's own app, and use it to test your favorite bible passages. Choose either the downloads or the PDF in the center column.](http://https:/http://www.modernliteralversion.org/) 
Does it prove to be a better translation than the one you use? And/Or would it create fewer philosophical arguments by hermeneutical standard?**

I've only recently discovered it and all that I have read so far impresses me. I was able to put it into Logos as a self-made book that does almost everything I require of it.

It is an Open Source project that has been going on for nearly 30 years! Anyone having a point to make is considered. I have only made one point which if adopted may be more personal than it needs to be, but I have been accepted with very friendly welcomes.

Here's the page that will lead you to all your questions: http://www.modernliteralversion.org/  Choose either the downloads or the PDF in the center column.

Comment: I think the question could have been posed differently, but according to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions about  "translation of Biblical texts" are on topic (i.e. the question should not be closed because it "does not appear to be about the analysis of biblical text within the scope defined in the help center."  It does seem terribly broad though.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't know how to judge the reliability of a translation where anyone can submit any correction at any time.  It means that what seems a reliable translation today could easily end up being corrupt tomorrow.

Comment: I'll read your link to "What topics can I ask about here?" However, I answer your point about "the reliability of a translation where anyone can submit any correction at any time." Like you I didn't click on your link to consider your point, so I ask that you too would find your question answered very satisfactorily on MLV's home page. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @DonWood I looked at your link. I cannot find any reference to 1) the Greek Text you are using and 2) to the contributors contributing and 3) to the qualifications of the contributors.

Comment: @Nigel J the link is correct. In the center column pick one of the downloads or the .PDF and all are free.

Comment: EJoshuaS "there is no problem to be solved?" Hmmmmm. I find 66 books worth of potential problems. May I suggest you look up your favorite biblical passages and determine from a hermeneutical and translational view what you would do to solve what problems. May I also say that I do not personally know of a publisher that doesn't sell their own views within the holy text? If you know of another, I'd like to hear of it. If the MLV doesn't score with your own translation, is the MLV wrong or yours? I find this a definite hermeneutical question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of such overly rigid and literal translations.  They incorrect imply that the two languages (Greek and English here) have exact synonyms which is so obviously untrue.

- Translating "angelos" uniformly as "messenger" is misleading.
- Translating "logos" and "rhema" as "word" is misleading.
- Translating "agape" and "philos" uniformly as love is misleading.

I also not that some words are not translated uniformly such as:

- "sabbath" is sometimes translated as "sabbath" and sometimes (correctly) translated as "week".
- "skene" is sometimes translated "tent" and sometimes (correctly) translated "resided"
- "psyche" is sometimes translated "life" and sometimes translated "soul"

Therefore, they are discovering what the NET Bible discovered - rigid literalism does not and cannot work.  Words change their meaning, sometimes quite dramatically, depending on context.

Lastly, overly literal translations, while they have their places, can be a source of mis-information when they miss the variety of possible meanings available.  This is why it is much better to use a variety of translations to help ensure that some of the subtleties in the text are noticed.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Peter McGowan. I appreciate your finds and will take them myself, if you do not, to inquire about these things.

Comment: Peter McGowan, I have a reply to your points.

Comment: CONTINUATION: you are mixing nouns with verbs. 
"I am tenting" or the true literal "I am tabernacling" is not understandable to any normal English person.  ome Greek words have literal meanings and some have figurative meanings as used in context.  A truly uniform accurate translation uses either form uniformly all the way. The MLV does this.

The last is the worse thing the 'dynamic equal' people ever came up with to attempt to proof 'literal' vs. 'paraphrase'.  Some Greek word truly have multiple meanings. Some are idioms either Greek or English, 
CONTINUED

Comment: CONTINUATION:  "I don't fight UPON you" but to say "I will beat **upon** you' would be understandable. Or better 'I fight against you'. So more Lexicon add "against" to EPI. 

install the Modern Literal Version module in e-Sword, MyBible, MySword and soon our own app, to see we put these in the "Supplement" sections of the Lexicon so people can see the 'literal' 'figurative' 'synonym' 'idiom' aspects of the word. CONTINUED

Comment: FINAL Unlike EVERY other translation on this planet in English all of this info 3400 pages is available at a couple clicks of your mouse. That is accuracy and that is uniformity. 

The Modern Literal Version is the only "Open Source" so anyone who truly has a "Thus saith the Greek" correction to submit can.  The MLV is also the ONLY translation on this planet in English that has a 'Concordance', "Lexicon" and "Greek Concordance" linked to it electronically or thru a couple of extra books "The New Koine Greek Textbooks Vol. I, II, III" all available on amazon as is the MLV.

Comment: I think you have missed the point.  John 3 is a perfect example of the problems that rigid literalism creates.  John 3: - "the spirit is blowing..."??  Yet another word, "anothen" is translated (correctly) "anew" in v3 & 7, yet is (correctly) translated "above" in v31.  This is NOT uniformity but is correct.  The same approach should be used for more important words like "pneuma" as well, but is not.

Comment: Some of your claims are factually incorrect.  There are numerous Bible translations freely available "at a couple of mouse clicks".  The open source dose not automatically make a translation better it just makes it democratic and thus popular but not necessarily best nor optimum.  The example I gave above are only a sample of its faults which will presumably be defended.  The best approach is to use a variety of translation - none is perfect.